# sklearn classification metric auc return ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, auc

I'm building a two class classification model using KNN

I tried to calculate auc_score with

```
from sklearn.metrics import auc

auc(y_test, y_pred)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-183-980dc3c4e3d7> in <module>
----> 1 auc(y_test, y_pred)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/ranking.py in auc(x, y, reorder)
    117             else:
    118                 raise ValueError("x is neither increasing nor decreasing "
--> 119                                  ": {}.".format(x))
    120 
    121     area = direction * np.trapz(y, x)

ValueError: x is neither increasing nor decreasing : [1 1 1 ... 1 1 1].
```

Then I used `roc_auc_score`

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred)
0.5118361429056588
```

Why is it `auc` is not working where as `roc_auc_score` is working. I though they both were same? What am I missing here?

Here `y_test` is actual target values and `y_pred` is my predicted values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are different in implementation and meaning:

[`auc`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.auc.html):

> Compute Area Under the Curve (AUC) using the trapezoidal rule.
> This is a general function, given points on a curve.

[`roc_auc_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html):

> Compute Area Under the Receiver Operating Characteristic Curve (ROC AUC) from prediction scores.

It means `auc` is more general than `roc_auc_score`, although you can get the same value of `roc_auc_curve` from `auc`. Hence, the input parameter of the `auc` is the `x` and `y` coordinates of the specified curve, and your error comes from the difference in types of necessary input! Also, the `x` and `y` must be in an increasing or decreasing order.

Comment: why am I receiving ValueError when using auc function?

Comment: Can I know what you mean by x and y coordinates? Do you mean actual values and predicted values?

Comment: @user214 `x` and `y` coordinates of a curve that you want to compute its `auc`. They must be in an increasing or decreasing order.

Answer (score 2):

- As pointed here: [What does AUC stand for and what is it?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132777/what-does-auc-stand-for-and-what-is-it)

> AUC is used most of the time to mean AUROC, which is a bad practice since as Marc Claesen pointed out AUC is ambiguous (could be any curve) while AUROC is not.

- For binary classification you need to use the metric ROC AUC not Area
  under Curve.

As for why the value error occurs in AUC is due to the following error

> x is neither increasing nor decreasing : [1 1 1 ... 1 1 1]

The [auc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.auc.html) metric uses [trapezoid rule](https://nptel.ac.in/courses/122104018/node120.html) to approximate the area under curve and trapeziod rule requires regular interval sampled function i.e it requires input as following for a function  y = exp(x^2)

> X : 0.0,  0.1,    0.2,    0.3,    0.4
>
> Y : 1.00000   1.01005     1.04081     1.09417     1.17351

Therefore X should be either monotonic increasing or monotonic decreasing and Y is just the output of the function at that point.

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is:

for auc, you need to sort the input arrays